# Dynamically remove event from YOAST sitemap if custom field has value

Tags: php, wordpress, sitemap, yoast

I have a wordpress site with over 100 events which all have a redirect. I want to exclude these from the sitemap ("3xx redirect in sitemap"-error). I'm using YOAST to create the sitemap.

The way this works is the events have a Custom Field(ev_external_link) where you input the link you want the event to redirect to.

What I need is to dynamically remove all events from the YOAST sitemap that have value in the "ev_external_link"-field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use that hook `wpseo_exclude_from_sitemap_by_post_ids` https://developer.yoast.com/features/xml-sitemaps/api/
try code like that

```
    /**
     * Excludes posts from XML sitemaps.
     *
     * @return array The IDs of posts to exclude.
     */
    function exclude_posts_from_xml_sitemaps() {
      // get events with meta ev_external_link
      $ids = get_posts(
        'post_type'     => 'event',
        'meta_key'      => 'ev_external_link',
        'post_status'   =>  array('draft', 'publish'),
        'numberposts'   =>  -1,
        'fields'        => 'ids'
      );
      if ($ids && is_array($ids)){
        return $ids;
      }
    }

add_filter( 'wpseo_exclude_from_sitemap_by_post_ids', 'exclude_posts_from_xml_sitemaps' );
```